# Set language cookie on page visit with CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, cookies, internationalization

I want to set a cookie whenever a user visits a page, so not only the home page but also people that find the site through google.

On every page I need to check wheter or not the user has a cookie set with his language.
If no cookie i set make one if there is one, don't do anything.

Can I make a function that I can load on every page? If so, how?

I'm using the codeIgniter framework with i18n 2.1 for multi language.

I also have a second question:
I'm using i18n for multi language. I've set nl as the first language in the array:

```
private $languages = array(
    'nl' => 'dutch',
    'en' => 'english',
    'de' => 'german',
    'fr' => 'french'        
);
```

but everytime you visit my base url, en, english, is loaded. Am I missing something?

Edit: I just can't seem to get the correct language to load. the cookie is set to dutch but when I go to the base url and check what cookies is loaded it just ignores the cookie and loads the english home page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question:

To make a function that runs on every page you need to extend the base Controller class. Pretty good instructions are here:

http://codeigniter.com/wiki/MY_Controller_-_how_to_extend_the_CI_Controller

You will make a file called MY_controller.php and put in in /application/core/.

Then inside the constructor method of the extension you can call functions that will run on every page.

I am not sure about your second question. I have always just built language systems separately and let the users choose their language.

Comment: Thanks, that works great, but setting a language cookies isn't useful if I can't use it >_> So now for problem 2.